# In Power-Bi, consider sales of the last/previous non blank quarter if the previous quarter is blank (not having any value/sales)?

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

In Power-Bi, I have two tables:

```
CALENDER_DIM: [ENDOFMONTH, YEAR, QUARTER, QUARTERNUM]

SALES_FACT: [ENDOFMONTH, PRODUCTID, SALE`S]
```

I want to show a comparison of the current quarter's sales with the previous quarter's sales, and I am using these measures:

```
Sales - This Quarter = SUM(SALES_FACT[SALES])

Sales - Previous Quarter (Having Sales) = CALCULATE([Sales - This Quarter],PREVIOUSQUARTER(CALENDAR_DIM[ENDOFMONTH]))
```

Currently, for the **Sales - Previous Quarter** column if the previous quarter is not having any sales, it is showing Blank:

[image]

But what I want to achieve is that: **if the previous quarter is blank, consider the last/previous non-blank quarter sales**:

Expected output:

[image]

So, for 2021, Q2 was null/blank, in that case for 2021 Q3 for the Sales - Previous Quarter column, **instead of considering 2021 Q2, consider 2021 Q1.**

Similarly, for 2022, Q1 is not having any sales and it is blank, so for 2022 Q2 for the Sales - Previous Quarter column, **instead of considering 2022 Q1, consider 2021 Q4 (Which is having sales).**

**In short, if the previous quarter is blank, consider the latest previous quarter which is having any sales.**

Any guidance or help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the DAX function LASTNONBLANK(column,expression)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lastnonblank-function-dax

I think this function can help you.

Regards,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).